# CSS span floating

Tags: html, css

In the following HTML, I want to display the span and h2 on the same line, both floating to the left. The span has less text in it, but h2 has more, so it should continue to the next line, but seems that I am doing something wrong:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <span>hello</span>
    <h2>This should start after the span, and continue to next line.</h2>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div{  
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

span{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border:1px solid green;
}

h2{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/ZnSBJ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float:left` from the `h2` and change `inline-block to inline`

```
h2{
  display: inline;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnSBJ/2/)**

---

If you want h2 to act like box then specify the width

```
h2{
  display: inline-block; width:100px
}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnSBJ/3/)**